# When does Starship Troopers take place?

Tags: starship-troopers, setting

Do any of the various versions and remakes of *Starship Troopers* give a dates as to when they take place?

I'm fine with answers from

- The original novel
- The anime
- The film series
- The RPG
- The various video and board games
- The CGI television series
- Any of the three liscenced comic series
- Anything else that's officially licensed

Comment: Damn, I hate myself. I love the movies (except the second one, that one sucks) and I own the 4 of them and I cant answer this cuz I dont know LOL. At least I can give you a thumbs up.

Comment: I saw mentions of 23rd century but no cites.

Comment: @DVK - Verhoeven says "23rd Century" in the commentary, apparently. There's also some dates listed in the comics serials.

Comment: @Richard - ugh. Verhoeven didn't even read the book. I thought it was a reliable source.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

### The film is (probably) set in the 23rd century.

The slightly altered David Bowie lyrics for the song "I've not been to Paradise" used in the high school dance towards the end of the film contains the line:

> "All is well. Watch the days go by. All is well. 23rd century dies."

And according to [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/23rd_century), the director has confirmed this explicitly:

> Starship Troopers is placed in the 23rd century, as said by Paul Verhoeven in the director's commentary.

The only commentary I've found on Youtube is [this one](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=VkOqiweYfwQ) by Verhoeven and screenwriter Edward Neumeier, but Verhoeven also did at least one other commentary together with some of the acting cast, as referenced [here](https://news.google.com/newspapers?nid=1955&dat=20020613&id=xgEyAAAAIBAJ&sjid=LaMFAAAAIBAJ&pg=4086,8071944&hl=en). I haven't found a video or transcript of this commentary though to confirm the 23rd-century reference.

Comment: I never realized that was a Bowie song... always liked it in the movie though!

Comment: The commentary says "**Verhoeven:** *The Song you will be hearing is a David Bowie Song". It's called "You've never been to Oxford Town"* - **Ed Neumeier**: *It's actually the only sense of a date we put on the picture because the lyric is talking about the end of the 23rd Century*"

Comment: For the record, Verhoeven has done three commentaries, one with Ed Neumeier, one with three of the cast leads (Rico, Dizzy, Carl) and one with the film's special effects guys which is the most boring commentary ever made.